# Solving the differential equation ${x^3}y''(x) + {x}y' - y =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE but cannot get a method which works for solving it as it is not in any standard form.  I am able to solve it via Maple but could someone advise what the way of solving it by hand would be?

$${x^3}y''(x) + {x}y' - y =0$$

Reduction of order relies on already knowing a linearly independent solution and variation of parameters is just a general method for an inhomogeneous linear ODE.  The auxiliary equation type of solution which I have used before seems to rely on the coefficients essentially being in the form of a quadratic equation and methods for constant coefficients obviously don't work as they are variable here.

Comment: Why does reduction of order rely on a solution?

Comment: one of the solutions is $y(x)=cx$

Comment: Yes Kiryl, you're right.  You can see that this is a solution by inspection and then use reduction of order.  I feel like that would be the most straightforward way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sustituting $$y(x)=xu(x)$$ then we get $$x^4u''(x)+x^2u'(x)(2x+1)=0$$ now let $$u'(x)=v(x)$$
then we have to solve
$$\int\frac{v'(x)}{v(x)}dx=\int\frac{-2x-1}{x^2}dx$$